# Consulta y Validaciones en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validación

Estoy haciendo una página en la cual los usuarios pueden pedir accesos a áreas diferentes de una empresa para eso manejo 2 modelos Accesos y otro Request

El problema:

Se desea que los usuarios ingresen el código de acceso(codacc es único no se repite) y este se valide a cuál acceso pertenece y luego guarde su id_acceso en la tabla request (la idea es que los usuarios no tengan los id de acceso)

Las tablas:

```
 create_table "accesses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "area",      limit: 255
    t.string   "codacc",      limit: 255 => Unique
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end


  create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "access_id",  limit: 4            =>reference a model access
    t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 4            =>reference  a model user
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
end
```

Los modelos:

Access.rb:

```
class Access < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
end
```

Request.rb  /// Aquí es donde está el problema real

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :access
  belongs_to :user
  validate :access_id_exists

Protected

#///////////////// Aqui el problema
    def access_id_exists

      if Access.exists?(:codacc => self.access_id) then  (compruebo que exista ese codigo que ingreso)
          self.access_id = (aqui tengo que cambiar el código de acceso por el id del acceso) 
      else
          errors.add(:access_id, 'A valid bar_id is valid. ')
      end
    end
end
```

El  controller request:

```
def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    @request.user_id = current_user.id   //cambio el id user que pide el form por el usuario actual

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render @request, status: :created, location: @request}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien tu problema, creo que estás buscando el objeto `Access` en el lugar equivocado, considero que sería mejor asignar el valor de `access_id` adecuado en el controlador, no en el modelo; por ejemplo:

```
def create
  request_hash = {
    access_id: Access.find_by(codacc: request_params[:access_id]).try(:id),
    user_id:   current_user.id
  }

  @request = Request.new(request_hash)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @request.save
      format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render @request, status: :created, location: @request}
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Un cambio importante es la creación de `request_hash` para asignar los valores del nuevo `Request` ahí, en lugar de crearlo directamente con `request_params` y después actualizarlo (como lo estabas haciendo).

El problema con utilizar `request_params` para crear el `Request` es que `access_id` es un `integer` pero le asignas un `string`, lo que traduce como `0`; por lo tanto es necesario primero obtener el `access_id` correcto **antes** de crear el nuevo `Request`.

`Access.find_by(codacc: @request.access_id).try(:id)` buscará el objeto `Access` con `codacc = @request.access_id` y, en caso que exista te devolverá el `id`, en caso contrario quedará como `nil`.

Ahora en tu modelo únicamente tienes que validar que el valor de `access_id` esté presente, para lo que un simple `validates :access_id, presence: true` es suficiente:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :access
  belongs_to :user
  validates :access_id, presence: { message: "A valid bar_id is valid." }
end
```

Comment: Funciona bien en caso de que sea un codigo equivocado pero cuando es el codigo correcto esta leyendo en el query un 0 en vez de el codigo enviado por el form, esto me sale en la consola como ves el request esta bien ese el codigo para un area pero el query compara con 0  "request"=>{"access_id"=>"PNA-0608"}, "commit"=>"Create Request"}
  Access Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  `accesses`.* FROM `accesses` WHERE `accesses`.`codacc` = '0' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: @J.leo Ya ví el problema: estás asignando un `string` a `access_id` en `Request.new(request_params)`, pero ese campo es tipo `integer` por lo que el valor del código se interpreta como `0`. Mira la respuesta actualizada para solucionarlo.

Comment: Gracias funciono perfectamente